# Rotate icosahedron to camera with correct face?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have icosahedron in Three.js with a number on each  face, how can i rotate icosahedron, so user will see number that i want?
Icosahedron with numbers that i have:

```js
function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  // here i want to rotate to num 1 for example

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z8h62gb/